# Templated Lazy Initialization Singleton taking internal templated typedef as an argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, visual-c++, singleton

I have a vast amount of different enumerated types I do not control. For example (1 of several 100s of enums):

```
enum ColorType {
    RED,
    GREEN,
    BLUE };
```

I am looking to allow C++ clients to bind any std::string they wish to the individual values of the enumerated type (but unique in a bi-directional way). I got this to work using a boost bimap (v1.60) - ignore bounds checking etc. here:

```
template <typename L, typename R> boost::bimap<L, R>
        makeBimap(std::initializer_list<typename boost::bimap<L, R>::value_type> list)
        {
            return boost::bimap<L, R>(list.begin(), list.end());
        };

template<typename E> class EnumWithString 
{
private:
    typedef typename boost::bimap<E, std::string > BMEnumType;
    const BMEnumType _biMap;

    EnumWithString(const EnumWithString<E>&) = delete;
    EnumWithString& operator=(const EnumWithString<E>&) = delete;
public:
    EnumWithString(const BMEnumType& biMap) : _biMap(biMap) {};
    const std::string& getString(const E& e) const {
        return this->_biMap.left.at(e);
    }
    const E& getEnum(const std::string& s) const {
        return this->_biMap.right.at(s);
    }
};
```

makes for example client code (feel free to imagine the typedefs for readability):

```
EnumWithString<ColorType> stringBoundEnum(makeBimap<ColorType, std::string>({ { ColorType::RED, "Rouge" },  
{ ColorType::BLUE, "Bleu" },                                                                                  
{ ColorType::GREEN, "Vert" } }));
    cout << stringBoundEnum.getString(ColorType::GREEN) << endl;
    cout << stringBoundEnum.getEnum("Bleu") << endl;
```

Which gives the correct output. The gnarly bit is that I need these created mappings (e.g. `stringBoundEnum`) to be Singletons, i.e. I am looking for an interface like (again imagine typedefs):

```
EnumWithStringSingleton<ColorType>::setInstance(makeBimap<ColorType, std::string>({ { ColorType::RED, "Rouge" },
                                                                              { ColorType::BLUE, "Bleu" },
                                                                              { ColorType::GREEN, "Vert" } })); // called only once by client

cout << EnumWithStringSingleton<ColorType>::getInstance().getString(ColorType::GREEN) << endl;
```

Ideally I am looking for something that works with templated Singleton taking a single CTOR argument like:

```
template <typename T, typename CTORArgument> class LazyInitSingleton
{
public:
    static T& getInstance(const CTORArgument& arg)
    {
        static T& theInstance(arg);
        return theInstance;
    }       
private:
};
```

The problem is that for my case the `CTORArgument` is a templated typedef defined inside a template class. I would be curious to see how people solve this (SFINAE perhaps?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is to make your singleton more specific for the needs of `EnumWithString`:

```
template <typename EnumWithStringType> class LazyInitSingleton
{
public:
    // You have to make BMEnumType public
    static EnumWithStringType& getInstance(const typename EnumWithStringType::BMEnumType& arg)
    {
        static EnumWithStringType theInstance(arg);
        return theInstance;
    }
};

LazyInitSingleton<EnumWithStringType<ColorType>>::getInstance(...);
```

Or even

```
template <typename EnumType> class LazyInitSingleton
{
public:
    static EnumWithString<EnumType>& getInstance(const EnumWithString<EnumType>::BMEnumType& arg)
    {
        static EnumWithString<EnumType> theInstance(arg);
        return theInstance;
    }
};

LazyInitSingleton<ColorType>::getInstance(...);
```

Comment: Yes, this works great. I think my mind was too set on keeping the Singleton class generic, thus overly complicating the structure. To make it compile I added the typename so it recognizes `BMEnumType` but the the right idea is there: `typedef typename boost::bimap<EnumType, std::string > BMEnumType;` and `static EnumWithString<EnumType>& getInstance(const BMEnumType& arg)` on the signature. Thanks!